# How to save bulk data in J2me for offline use?

Tags: database, java-me

I an developing a J2ME application in which i want to store bulk of data in the form of DB in mobile memory.What will be best approach to store and retrieve large amount of data. All the ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either save it in an [RMS RecordStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html) or save it to a file using [JSR 75](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/microemu/microemu-jsr-75/2.0.2/microemu-jsr-75-2.0.2-javadoc.jar!/index.html).

Comment: how much data i can store with RMS, and what about the performance? Roughly there can be 20000 records, and also i have to perform some operations on that data...

Comment: Instead of asking me you will have much better results if you actually try storing the data on the device, and see if it holds it all.  And observe the performance times and see if that meets your needs.